# Able to access URL from local tomcat instance but not from production server - Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security

When i try to hit the below URL from production server i am getting 404 in firefox console where as when i hit the same from local tomcat instance it is working fine.

URL - http://www.nattukottainagarathar.com/profile/pirivu/1 404 Not found - **Not working**

localhost:8080/NattukottaiNagarathar/profile/pirivu/1 - **Working**

http://www.nattukottainagarathar.com/user/profile/pirivu/1 - **Working**

I've used spring security. I have configured spring security in such as way that it directs the user to login screen when a url with /user is accessed but in my case '/profile/pirivu/1' is not working but it is working with /user/profile/pirivu/1. Why it is working in local tomcat instance and not working in prod instance. It should work without /user.

In my .js file the control comes till

```
$.getJSON("profile/pirivu/"+selectedKovilValue,function(data)
```

after that i am getting 404 Not found exception

**Spring security**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/welcome"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userManager" >
        <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />    
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

**register.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#kovil").change(function() {
    $('#pirivu').prop('disabled', false);

    var selectedKovilValue = $("#kovil").val();
    var pirivuType = $("#pirivu");
    if (selectedKovilValue == 0) {
        pirivuType.empty();
        pirivuType.append("<option value='0'>-- Please choose kovil from above -- </option>");
        pirivuType.val(0);
        pirivuType.prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $.getJSON("profile/pirivu/"+selectedKovilValue,function(data) {
            if(selectedKovilValue!=0)
            {
                pirivuType.empty();
                pirivuType.append("<option value='0'>-- Select --</option>");
                $.each(data,function(index,value) {
                    if(selectedKovilValue==value.kovilId){
                    pirivuType.append("<option value='" + value.pirivuId + "'>"+ value.pirivu+ "</option>");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/profile/pirivu/{kovil}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Pirivu> gePirivu(@PathVariable("kovil") String kovil) {
    List<Pirivu> pirivuObjs = serviceManager.getPirivu(kovil);
    return pirivuObjs;
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>www.nattukottainagarathar.com</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Is the security configuration exactly same in localhost vs prod? Can you post the whole security configuration xml?

Comment: It is same. I have updated the post with the whole spring security configuration. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try with `<csrf disabled="true"/>`?

Comment: It looks like Spring 3 doesn't have <csrf disabled="true"/>. I just removed <csrf /> but still it is not working.

Comment: Is `error-page="/403"` pointing to a valid mapping?

Comment: it is pointing to valid mapping. After deleting  <csrf /> from spring security. I am able to access the url http://www.nattukottainagarathar.com/user/profile/pirivu/8 (It is up and running. You can hit the url and check) without loggin in. But still http://www.nattukottainagarathar.com/profile/pirivu/8 is not working. I don't have any request mapping with /user/profile/pirivu/. I have mapping only with /profile/pirivu/. Not sure why it is working only with /user/profile/pirivu

Comment: Can you post web.xml?

Comment: In my previous comment i mentioned after deleting <csrf> i was able to access. That is wrong. Actually i was not able to see any changes after deleting <csrf>. I was able to access the URL http://www.nattukottainagarathar.com/user/profile/pirivu/8 after removing eveything in spring-security config file. I have added web.xml in my original posting. I got struck with this for the past 4 days. I appreciate your help.

Comment: This is the URL where i am facing problem. http://www.nattukottainagarathar.com/register.html Based on Kovil dropdown Piruvu dropdown will be populated. But it is not happening.

Comment: Looks like you have multiple `servlet-mapping` for `DispatcherServlet`. Can you remove the one with `url-pattern: /user/*`?

Comment: Actually i added /user/* since i was getting some issues with tiles. I tried removing that. Still same. It didn't fix the issue.